# cutepdf don't show my google chart in ie8

Tags: html, pdf, internet-explorer-8, google-visualization

Im trying to export my page (with some google charts) to pdf with the cutepdf extention, it's works fine with chrome and ie9, but in ie8 the chart is not visible, instead is blank space.

any idea?

***Example:***

**JSFIDDLE**

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/7wYP2/) is a link to a jsfiddle with a working chart if anyone needs it to do some tests

**CODE**

```js
<div id="visualization"></div>

google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});

function drawVisualization() {
    // Create and populate the data table.
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Year', 'Austria', 'Belgium', 'Czech Republic', 'Finland', 'France', 'Germany'],
        ['2003',  1336060,   3817614,       974066,       1104797,   6651824,  15727003],
        ['2004',  1538156,   3968305,       928875,       1151983,   5940129,  17356071],
        ['2005',  1576579,   4063225,       1063414,      1156441,   5714009,  16716049],
        ['2006',  1600652,   4604684,       940478,       1167979,   6190532,  18542843],
        ['2007',  1968113,   4013653,       1037079,      1207029,   6420270,  19564053],
        ['2008',  1901067,   6792087,       1037327,      1284795,   6240921,  19830493]
    ]);

    // Create and draw the visualization.
    new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
    draw(data, {
        title:"Yearly Coffee Consumption by Country",
        width:600, height:400,
        hAxis: {
            title: "Year"
        }
    });
}

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
```

thanks

Comment: I don't have an IE8 laptop in front of me, but I will in a couple of hours. In any case, I've invariably found that IE8's JS interpreter fails when others succeed. Have you tried just looking for subtle "errors" in the JS code you've given. I don't see anything offhand, but I know IE8 is super picky. I'd look for trailing commas (again I don't see any).

Comment: Also, here's a comment from the manager of the Google Charts API: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-visualization-api/orwant/google-visualization-api/luqbYcoY754/RQNZsO6DpYcJ

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a bug with IE8 printing VML. The easiest solution would be to force the page into IE7 compatibility mode.

See http://www.mattesch.info/blog/printing-vml-and-other-printing-bugs-with-ie8/ for more details and other solutions.